# Parallel Processing how to distribute load amonst processors. or to specify which processor will carry out a task

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

i have to determining which processor is busy and send tasks to processor that arent as busy instead. i have to execute a program using parallel python but i also have to determind which of the servers to send the task to. does any one no what kind of conditions i should use on the parallel processing codes? and its written in python calling PP

Answer (score 0):

If you have any choice in the matter (which you might not if this is a homework assignment) you might want to consider using [ØMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/) to handle messaging amongst the various bits of your system. On the [Learn page](http://www.zeromq.org/intro%3aread-the-manual) there is an excellent (and very rapid fire) presentation by Ian Barber. It's 45 minutes and well worth watching. It fundamentally changed the way I think about messaging and multi-thread / process / processor communication. It was so information-dense I had to watch it twice and then start doing toy programs to wrap my head around just how clean the whole concept is.

Note: although the language he uses for the presentation is PHP, the code examples he shows would look almost identical in any of the over 20 languages that ØMQ supports. (Multi-process COBOL anyone? :-)